# Prove $\tan\big(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \big) = \cot \theta$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right) =  \cot \theta$$

I can prove this by changing into $\cos$ and $\sin$

But I want to know if it is possible to prove it using relation given below. If not why ?
$$\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right) =\frac{ \tan\frac{\pi}{2} -\tan\theta}{1+ \tan\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\theta} $$

Comment: Use definition of $tan=\frac{sin}{cos}$ and then cofunction identities for sine and cosine. That avoids the tan90 issue

Comment: Have you read the whole question ?

Comment: Well $\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ might prove problematic.

Comment: Yes, you can prove it like you indicated you didn't do it. Your approach you showed does not work because of the tangent domain...

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But you need to take the limit of that expression for, say,  $\tan(\phi - \theta)$ as $\phi$ approaches $\pi/2$, instead of writing the expression at that value.

Answer (score 4):

No, it isn't possible with the identity in your question because $\tan \frac\pi2$ is not defined.  It isn't defined because $\cos \frac\pi 2 = 0$, and $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ in general.

Actually, it's exactly this fact ($\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$) that you'll want to use.  I'll get you started:

$$
  \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right) = \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x\right)}{\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - x \right)}
   = \frac{\sin\frac\pi 2 \cos x - \cos \frac\pi 2 \sin x}{\cos \frac\pi 2 \cos x + \sin\frac \pi 2 \sin x}
$$

Of course it'd be simpler to use the cofunction identities $\sin(\frac \pi 2 - x) = \cos x$ and $\cos(\frac \pi 2 - x) = \sin x$, but I'm assuming that's not allowed (or you want something different) because your original question is basically asking for an explanation of the tangent cofunction identity.

Edit: Many other answers are mentioning limits, etc.  Technically those will work but I'm assuming you're currently a trig student, which means it's unlikely you've had formal exposure to limits, and especially to l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: I am aware of limits and L Hopital

Comment: @AakashKumar. When you use any method that uses the derivative of the tangent to prove your identity, you better be sure that in that process you do not need your identity in the first place (circular reasoning). So using the limit definition of the tangent falls right outside the mechanism here. So how do you find the derivative of the trig functions without sum difference formulas? Unless this concern is not answered, Tilper's answer is the cleanest.

Answer (score 2):

The RHS of the relation
$$
\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2} -\theta \right) =\frac{ \tan\frac{\pi}{2} -\tan\theta}{1+ \tan\frac{\pi}{2}\tan\theta}
$$
evaluates to $\infty\over\infty$, an indeterminate form. However, if you apply L'Hopital's rule, you get
$$
\lim _{x\to\pi/2-}\frac{ \tan x -\tan\theta}{1+ \tan x\tan\theta}=\lim _{x\to\pi/2-}\frac{\sec^2x}{\sec^2x\tan\theta}=\cot\theta,
$$
and the same result obtains for the limit as $x\to\pi/2+$.

Comment: And what if $\theta$ approaches $\pi/2$? Your limit situation changes. You are now assuming that $\theta$ is a "dummy" variable

Comment: @imranfat Yes, this argument is valid for each $\theta\ne\pi/2$. (And $\theta=0$ is problematic too.)

Comment: Please see my concern posted to Mryoumath...

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{a\rightarrow (\pi/2),a<\pi/2}\frac{ \tan a  -\tan\theta}{1+ \tan a\tan\theta}=\lim_{a\rightarrow (\pi/2),a<\pi/2}\frac{\tan a}{\tan a \tan \theta} =\frac 1{\tan\theta}$$
$$\lim_{a\rightarrow (\pi/2),a>\pi/2}\frac{ \tan a  -\tan\theta}{1+ \tan a\tan\theta}=\lim_{a\rightarrow (\pi/2),a>\pi/2}\frac{\tan a}{\tan a \tan \theta}=\frac 1{\tan\theta} $$

Hence
$$\tan(\pi/2 -\theta)=\frac 1{\tan\theta}$$

Comment: Your $\lim$ algebra is off. The dummy variable $a$ should disappear when you evaluate the limit.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Sorry, I'm used to the shorthand. I've fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First consider

$$\tan(x-\theta)=\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(\theta)}$$

Now take the limit $x \to \pi/2 $ and use L'hospital:

$$\tan(\pi/2-\theta)=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\tan(x-\theta)=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{\tan(x)-\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan(x)\tan(\theta)}=\lim_{x\to \pi/2}\frac{1+\tan^2(x)}{\left(1+\tan^2(x)\right)\tan(\theta)}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}=\cot(\theta)$$

$$\tan(\pi/2-\theta)=\cot(\theta)$$

Note that I used $(\tan(x))'=1+\tan^2(x)$ and you still need to be carefull with the values you use for $\theta$.

Comment: What is the role of $\theta$ here? That can become $\pi/2$ as well.

Comment: $\theta$ is just a parameter in the limit. And $\theta=\pi/2$ is not allowed with this derivation, you would need to use a second limit in $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, that is a very important observation! Because $x$ has no preference over $\theta$ in the stated identity.

Comment: The other thing is that in L'Hospital, we use the derivative of the tangent. Now how do we find the derivative? Do we do that directly with the limit definition of through the quotient rule? Either way, we'd better had a derivative that does in no way rely on the OP's stated identity otherwise we have circular reasoning...

Comment: @imranfat: That is a good point, but the op didn't state that the derivative of $\tan(x)$ was not known. Even if it was not known you could derive it from the derivative of $\sin(x)$.

Comment: If the derivatives of sine and cosine are derived independently from the stated identity, sure!. My only concern is that I have seen "circular reasoning" more than once in calculating trig limits using L'Hospital Rule, hence my apprehension...

Comment: @imranfat: The OP explicitly told us that he knows the derivation by splitting up by sine and cosine, which is the trivial way to prove this. BTW even that splitting up cannot be proven without geometric reasoning. In modern mathematics sine and cosine are defined by a power series. And finding the derivative of a power is a piece of cake considering that it both functions have a infinite radius of convergence.

Answer (score -4):

If instead of $$\ tan (\frac{\pi}{2} - x)$$ We take 
$$ \lim_ {a \to \pi/2} \ tan(a-x)$$
Then $$\tan(a-x) = \frac{(\tan a  - \tan x)}{ (1+\tan (a)\tan(x))}$$ 
Divide by $\tan(a)$ and use $\frac{1}{\tan(a)}=0$